# How to write complex mathematical functions in shiny

Tags: r

I want to write a shiny wabpage which calculate sample size for clinical data. I have completed the calculating function, but I don't know how should I add the function to the shiny process.

This is my shiny code, which shows a simple calculation process. It can run, but I don't know how to calculate complex formulas.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
numericInput("p0", "p0:",0.5, min = 0, max = 1),
numericInput("p1", "p1:", 0.5,min = 0, max = 1),
numericInput("alpha", "significant level:", 0.05,min = 0, max = 1),
numericInput("power", "power:", 0.8,min = 0, max = 1),
textOutput("text_calc"))
))
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output,session){
  output$text_calc <- renderText({
p0 <- input$p0
p1 <- input$p1
alpha <- input$alpha
power = input$power
paste("The result is =", p0+p1+alpha+power)
  })
})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


mod1 = function(p0,p1,alpha,power,alternative){
  if (alternative == "one-sided"){
  z1_value = qnorm(1-alpha)
  z2_value = qnorm(power)
  delta = p1-p0
  size = ((z1_value*sqrt(p0*(1-p0))+z2_value*sqrt(p1*(1-p1)))/delta)^2
  }
  if (alternative == "two-sided"){
  z1_value = qnorm(1-(alpha/2))
  z2_value = qnorm(power)
  delta = p1-p0
  size = (((z1_value+z2_value)^2)*p1*(1-p1))/((delta)^2)
  }
  return(list(size = size))
}
```

How should I conbine the two codes together and make a shiny for the calculation? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code slightly:

```
library(shiny)

mod1 = function(p0,p1,alpha,power,alternative){
  if (alternative == "one-sided"){
  z1_value = qnorm(1-alpha)
  z2_value = qnorm(power)
  delta = p1-p0
  size = ((z1_value*sqrt(p0*(1-p0))+z2_value*sqrt(p1*(1-p1)))/delta)^2
  }
  if (alternative == "two-sided"){
  z1_value = qnorm(1-(alpha/2))
  z2_value = qnorm(power)
  delta = p1-p0
  size = (((z1_value+z2_value)^2)*p1*(1-p1))/((delta)^2)
  }
  return(list(size = size))
}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
        numericInput("p0", "p0:",0.5, min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.1),
        numericInput("p1", "p1:", 0.5,min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.1),
        numericInput("alpha", "significant level:", 0.05,min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.01),
        numericInput("power", "power:", 0.8,min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.1),
        selectInput("alternative", "alternative:", choices = c("one-sided", "two-sided")),
        textOutput("text_calc"))
))
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output,session){
    output$text_calc <- renderText({
        p0 <- input$p0
        p1 <- input$p1
        alpha <- input$alpha
        power = input$power
        alternative = input$alternative
        paste("The result is =", mod1(p0, p1, alpha, power, alternative))
    })
})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Your function `mod1` can be used as long as it is loaded in the global environment as above. The alternative is to split your app into different ui.R, server.R and global.R files. You can then put all required packages and functions in global.R. This is useful when apps get more complicated.

I have also added a step parameter in the numericInputs and a selectInput for the "alternative" although this could be a radio button as well as below:

```
radioButtons("alternative", "alternative:", choices = c("one-sided", "two-sided")),
```

There are other options, for example you could put the mod1 code within the renderText or utilise shiny's observes and reactives, depends on your preference and how your app is going to be used/its complexity.